# Как мне сделать автоматическое обновление программы

Tags: c#, windows, .net, webclient

Подскажите как сделать автоматическое обновление предложение на c#. Чтоб бесплатно и без лишних хостингом. Использовать какой-нибудь Mega или MediaFire.

Пытался сделать через google drive, но не получилось. Каждый раз скачивалась страница, а не файл. Через MediaFire пытался, но я не знаю как получить версию файла. Самый лёгкий способ конечно купить хостинг и туда все файлы обновления закидывать, но мне не хочется тратится на это пока что. Заранее спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: Скажите, а вы готовы дать свой компьютер даром, всем другим пользователям интернета? Ну, или хотяб свободное место на вашем жестком диске, готовы? Я думаю нет. Так почему кто-либо другой должен хотеть вам даром дать что либо, без получения от этого какой-либо выгоды? Облака — это совсем другая история, это не про передачу файлов, а про их хранение, где вас также ограничивают всячески, например почти любое облако заблокируется, если по этой ссылке скачает много человек один файл, им будет предложено скопировать файл к себе в облако. Или вон мега - пару гигов в день на ip.

Comment: Я использую бесплатную систему сборки, типа appveyor или travis. Там есть (были раньше по крайней мере) бесплатные планы. Процесс у меня выстроен так: после пуша в гитхаб система сборки триггерит новый билд и хранит его артифакты месяц. Юзеры нажимают кнопку «обновить» и качаются артифакты билда, ими обновляется прога. Но тут опенсурс, все всем доступно.

Comment: Если использовать Гугл драйв, то вам надо с его апи работать, получать ключи доступа и тд (возможно это платно, я не в курсе просто)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, мне не хост нужен, а через какое-нибудь облако это всё сделать. Через хост естественно не будет бесплатно.

Comment: @tym32167, нет, это вроде бесплатно, но с этим прижётся запариться...

Comment: @MIDDLE А я вам сказал хоть слово про хост? Я вам говорю, что бесплатный сыр только в мышеловке. У каждого бесплатного решения есть свои огромные минусы. Облачные сервисы я вам уже сказал - у них ограничения на скачивание, 15-20 человек скачало ваш файл, все, файл недоступен. Для вас это подходит? Если да, берите, если нет, ну все, облачные сервисы вам не подходят. Мега - также, в день может 1 ip скачать ограниченное число гб, да и чтоб скачать с меги, ух там сколько надо всего... Вам это подходит? Если да, берите, если нет, ищите дальше.

Comment: Я могу подсказать одно решение, прям вот как по мне лучшее - Appcenter от Microsoft. Но и тут есть свои проблемы, например - если у клиента старая версия Windows, без современных протоколов шифрования - у него нет доступа к сайту. Также это Microsoft, а они в последнее время плохо дружат с РУ, например сейчас у них урезана скорость (может глюк, хз), вот уже получите жалобы от РУ сегмента своих юзверов. Короче, везде есть свои минусы, в любом бесплатном решении, причем такие минусы, что проще свой комп под сервер отдать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, хорошо, если мне это решение пожойдёт то буду пользоваться, если нет, то скорее всего вложу хоть что-нибудь. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Интегрируй `syncthing`. Твой комп будет мастером, остальные будут помогать.